# AddOrUpdate method of ConcurrentDictionary always do lock (not skip if values equals)

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I read code of AddOrUpdate method in [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,7996972d3d91c9d0) and saw that if oldValue and newValue are equaled the method will do the update anyway. Is it true? Did i understand it correct? Because of it the method always do lock.

**update:** When i saw the code of method AddOrUpdate i think "why we need use TryUpdate with lock if oldValue equals newValue? We can check equaling and return if values equals" Because of it i asked this question.

I understood why this method always do update or add, without checking equals of oldValue and newValue. TValue is object and we can't compare it without overwriting method equals.

Because of it, if you want AddOrUpdate without lock your ConcurrentDictionary when oldValue and newValue is equals, you need to create method with your classes. I don't know how you can do it using generic.

Comment: what is "do lock" mean?

Comment: Because method TryAdd and method TryUpdate do lock. In the method AddOrUpdate always use TryAdd or TryUpdate.

Comment: yes , it always do lock , but why you want to ask this question?

Comment: What is a purpose of your question? `Did i understand it correct`, who knows how you understood it?

Comment: I haven't understood why we can't compare oldValue and newValue before TryUpdate and return if values is equals.

Comment: Because the method itself is not atomic and the old value used to compare can be stale at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ContainsKey` before the update.

`ContainsKey` calls `TryGetValue` which at [line 509](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,509) reads:

```
 // We can get away w/out a lock here.
```

:)

Comment: But ContainsKey not check value of key with newValue.

Answer (score -1):

I think Possible can do that ? Use `IEqualityComparer<TValue>` to compare first.

```
public TValue AddOrUpdate<TArg>(TKey key, Func<TKey, TArg, TValue> addValueFactory, Func<TKey, TValue, TArg, TValue> updateValueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
{
      // key exists, try to update
      if (TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
      {

           TValue newValue = updateValueFactory(key, oldValue, factoryArgument);
           IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
           if (valueComparer.Equals(oldValue, newValue))
           { return newValue; }
        }
        //...
    }
```

Comment: It's flawed because doesn't take into account concurrency.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov my bad , lock is required @@

Answer (score -2):

I understood why this method always do update or add, without checking equals of oldValue and newValue. TValue is object and we can't compare it without overwriting method equals.

Because of it, if you want AddOrUpdate without lock your ConcurrentDictionary when oldValue and newValue is equals, you need to create method with your classes. I don't know how you can do it using generic.

Comment: The method will either _Add_ or _Update_. Both actions require a lock. Your question and your answer are unclear.

Comment: This doesn't look as an answer but rather as part of the question. Please consider updating your question instead of spawning new posts which may confuse the readers in future.

Comment: When i saw the code of method AddOrUpdate i think "why we need use TryUpdate with lock if oldValue equals newValue? We can check equaling and return if values equals" Because of it i asked this question.

Comment: @КонстантинЗолин you can't or rather you can't do it safely. You'll have to make the entire process of value updating atomic (by wrapping it into `lock` for example) which will totally negate the benefits of `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov for example, i have ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>. Why I can't use it: if (TryGetValue(key, out oldValue)) { if (oldValue != newValue) TryUpdate(key, newValue, oldValue); } else { TryAdd(key, newValue) } . Why i need do it as atomic (into lock) ? I see only one problem, if it is generic method oldValue and newValue are objects and we can't equals it as int value.

Comment: @КонстантинЗолин because this conditional update isn't atomic. In other words, if there are couple of such calls executed concurrently and the `oldValue` happens to be read by any call just before the moment when it has been modified by another call, the call which obtained this stale value will "think" that the values are equal while in reality they are not (and won't update the item with new value).

Comment: @DmytroMukalov ok, i understand it. But what guarantees we that have when use AddOrUpdate method, that when we get value after updating, it will not changed by other TryUpdate method ? I am not good in English and have some problem in explaining my opinion. But we always check value or get value in some time, and we don't have guarantees that it will not change in future. Because of it does not matter will we check it before TryUpdate and returns or we use TryUpdate, and return value which not actual now, because was changed after updating.

Comment: @КонстантинЗолин, the `ConcurrentDictionary` implementation of `AddOrUpdate` doesn't return a non-actual value, neither it makes a wrong assumption to return prematurely, so it always returns value which is set by the operation, i.e. the actual one. It always makes an update because of fundamental concurrency problem that no assumption can be made about a state unless it happens inside an atomic operation. And as soon as `ConcurrentDictionary` uses only fine-grained locks to achieve less contention, the freshness of the value isn't guaranteed outside of these atomic blocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200355/discussion-between---and-dmytro-mukalov).